# Procurar por nome completo - ReactJS

Tags: regex, react

Ola, estou tentando criar um component Search e quando eu for pesquisar por exemplo nome completo ele me retornar o nome completo, porém ele só me retorna o nome
exemplo: **[Eu digito] Victor** - Ele retorna Victor, mas se eu digitar **"Victor Santos"** ele não me retorna nada.
Resumindo, gostaria de saber se pelo RegExp tem como retornar o nome completo

```js
function onSearch(e: any) {
  const search = e.target.value
  const searchFilter = myhook.data.filter((item: any) => {
    return !item.name.search(new RegExp(search, 'gi'))
  })
}
```

Comment: Victor, faltam muitas informações no seu código exemplo, as pessoas que forem tentar te ajudar não vão conseguir reproduzir seu cenário, sugiro que monte um exemplo que funcione e que reproduza seu erro no código anexado a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testar o array usando o regex assim:

```
let name = ["Vitor Santos", "Vitor silva", "antonia carolina"];
let stringTest = 'vitor';
```

// agora vamos testar e traser os resultados de um jeito mais simples

```
  let result = name.map(nam => { 
   if (RegExp(stringTest.toLowerCase()).test(nam.toLowerCase())) {
    return nam; 
   }
  })
```

// ele vai trazer os campos do array que tem pelo menos parte da string de teste e e convertemos todas as strings para minuscula

Comment: Se eu fizer a alteração da variavel **let stringTeste** por **let stringTest = e.target.value** ele funciona corretamente

Answer (score 0):

Então pessoal o Cláudio Silva, me deu uma ajuda e eu entendi melhor como deveria fazer abaixo está como a função esta.

```js
function onSearch(e: any) {
  const search = e.target.value
  const ScriptFilter = searchs.data.filter((item: any) => {
    if (RegExp(search.toLowerCase()).test(item.pdv.name.toLowerCase())) {
      return item
    }
  })
```

Agora eu consigo fazer a filtragem dos meus dados e retornar ele completo